# Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making my first React application. Upon making the frontend, I ran into the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:118:18)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:273:14)
    at moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:278:30)
    --- await ---
    at runMainESM (node:internal/modules/run_main:53:21)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:5)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
Process exited with code 1
```

This is my app.js file

```
import './App.css';
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/users").then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    
    <div className="App">
    
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I added "type": "module" to my package.json file and changed the file name of my app.js to app.mjs but it still didnt make any difference. This error is on the debugging console. When i run my app.js file using npm start this is the error displayed on the web browser:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:0-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\nayye\alumni-b\client\src'
Did you mean 'App.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './App' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in 'C:\Users\nayye\alumni-b\client\src'
Did you mean 'reportWebVitals.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './reportWebVitals' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

Comment: You don't need "type": "module" in your package.json (I have no idea what you mean by this but I would reverse it)... Secondly a react file is not a js file nor is it a mjs file... It is a `jsx` file. So perhaps try that. Make sure you have react and other dependencies correct... Did you use npx create-react-app to start your project? If so it should have been App.jsx to begin with.

Comment: It's not clear that any code you posted has anything to do with your error. It is a typical problem with accessing APIs that are *supposed* to return JSON but instead return an error page (with HTML formatting), but how that's related to what's in the question is a mystery.

Comment: Yes i used npx create-react-app, I am following a youtube tutorial and he also had an app.js file. I tried changing the file extension right now but it is giving typeerror, unknown file extension. I also removed the "type: "module" and now its giving the following error :     Uncaught SyntaxError C:\Users\nayye\alumni-b\client\src\App.jsx:1
import './App.css';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created the API host using whether json-sever or making it by yourself, if you already know express.js or node.js.

If you are just starting out, you better use json-server: see https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/json-server-for-frontend-development/
or https://dev.to/derick1530/introduction-to-json-server-beginner-part-i-4l2g

Once the server is running and you became able to access the information from the browser at https://localhost:3001/users then go on and test your existing code since it is not the problem at all.